# How to avoid crash in QQuickView?

Tags: qt, qml

Are there any ways to correclty close QQuickView without crashes? I posted [a bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39478) to Digia, but there still no response :(

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Rectangle
{
    id: root;
    signal quit();
    Component.onDestruction: quit();
    BusyIndicator
    {
        id: progress
        running: true
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

CPP:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QPointer>


int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    QGuiApplication a( argc, argv );
    QPointer< QQuickView > w = new QQuickView();

    QObject::connect( w, &QQuickView::statusChanged, [=]()
    {
        QObject::connect( w->rootObject(), SIGNAL( quit() ), qApp, SLOT( quit() ) );
    } );

    w->setSource( QUrl( "qrc:/test.qml" ) );
    w->setResizeMode( QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView );
    w->show();

    a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand wanting to post here as well, but to be fair, the report was created one day before the end of last week, with today being a public holiday. :p Within Digia, bugs are triaged whenever possible, but there are dedicated days every Tuesday: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-August/012394.html

Comment: Thanks, I need to unpack my mIRC client :)